# How is average cost in college scorecard derived?

Tags: collegescorecard

The Average Cost does not seem to be what the institution charges, how was it determined?

Comment: can you provide an example?

Answer (score 2):

The average net price is the full cost of attendance (including tuition and fees, books and supplies, and living expenses) minus federal, state, and institutional aid, for undergraduate students who receive federal aid (for public institutions, this metric is limited to undergraduates who pay in-state tuition).  This is calculated based on a weighted average of IPEDS net price data of undergraduate, Title IV-receiving students.